# Query about AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE

Tags: django

I have created two apps in to my single project.Now I wanted to get the profiles in both apps.So I wanted to know that how I design these apps in to **AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE**

Because it takes only one at a time e.g. **AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE=asd.Asd**

Can anybody tell how can I declare it for more than one app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Daniel Roseman said you can only have one user profile. So if you want to store user information specific to each app, you can create a model in the app and have `OneToOne` relation with main profile model.

Each app manages, manipulates the user attributes through its own model.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense. You don't have a profile per app, you have one single profile.